# Nvidia driver updated - mixed versions of 304.88 and 319.32

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg

My problem is that after trying to update my driver through the additional drivers GUI I can't boot Ubuntu with GUI anymore, since Xorg says the kernel module is of version 304.88 (The old version before I updated) but the driver components are of version 319.32 (The new version)

This is the output of dpkg -l | grep nvidia

```
dkpg -l | grep nvidia
ii nvidia-304 : 304.88-0ubuntu0.0.3
 NVIDIA binary Xord driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
ii nvidia-319 : 319.32-0ubuntu0.0.1
 NVIDIA binary Xord driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
ii nvidia-common : 1:0.2.44.2
 Find obselete NVIDIA drivers
ii nvidia-current : 304.88-0ubuntu0.0.3
 Transitional package for nvidia-current
ii nvidia-settings : 304.88-0ubuntu.0.0.3
 Transitional package for nvidia-settings
ii nvidia-settings-304 : 304.88-0ubuntu.0.0.3
 Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii nvidia-settings-319 : 319.32-0ubuntu.0.0.1
 Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

That's the output of that file.

The message startx gives me is:

NVIDIA: API mismatch: the NVIDIA kernel module has version 304.88, but this NVIDIA driver component has version 319.32. Please make sure that the kernel module and all NVIDIA driver components have the same version.

```
   Fatal server error:
   no screens found
```

I understand that something went wrong during the update, so I wonder how to fix this so that the remaining parts of 304 are removed and replaced with 319. I don't know hwere to start because I thought that nvidia-current was the one that would update to 319 and so reinstalling that didn't work. And I googled and found that somebody said to try to install/reinstall/uninstall this package: nvidia-current-updates-dev

But I didn't have that package installed so it did not help. Other than that, I am clueless. I hope the information I provided will be enough so I can get an answer soon.

EDIT:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise

uname -a
Linux SQuad 3.2.0-52-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 26 16:21:44 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/LINUX
```

Comment: It is clear from the errors that the latest `NVIDIA drivers` are meant for latest `Kernel`. So there are two options for you.. either your remove older version of `NVIDIA` drivers or `Install latest kernel`. Edit your question and paste the result of: `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a`

Comment: @SauravKumar I have done as you requested. I understand what needs to be done, I just don't know how to do it since it just says that nvidia-current is installed already and does not need to be upgraded/changed. And I wish to use 319 instead of 304 and I suspect nvidia-current is 304 (I'm not sure of this, but before when I tried upgrading with sudo apt-get install nvidia-current to get 319 it didn't do anything, so it stayed 304).

Comment: Ok I got your problem.. Your Kernel version is too old.. I don't know why it is showing 3.2.x in `Ubuntu 12.0.3 LTS`.. It should show 3.8.x. I am posting the way to install better kernel like 3.8.x as an answer.. Please give me some time.

Comment: check my answer..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of installing the latest version, I recommend you to install `Kernel` which is meant for `Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS` that is `Linux Kernel 3.8.0.30`. It is available in the repository so no need to go to some other place. Here is the steps to install `Kernel 3.8.0.30` for Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

- Execute following commands in series(one by one, if you get any error in any command just comment for the command for which you got the error with the error message)

  - Execute this to update repository:

    ```
    sudo apt-get update
    ```
  - Execute this to install `Kernel 3.8.x`(be careful, don't miss any character)

    ```
    sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-raring linux-headers-3.8.0-30 linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-raring linux-image-3.8.0-30-generic linux-image-generic-lts-raring
    ```
  - Execute this to update grub:

    ```
    sudo update-grub
    ```
  - Execute this to re-configure all installed packages(It would take some time, so wait. If it fails, gives some error just proceed to next step)

    ```
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
    ```
  - Execute this to restart your system:

    ```
    sudo reboot
    ```
- While restarting, you would see one more entry in `Grub Entry` for `Linux Kernel 3.8.0.30` chose that.
- See what happens.. Reply for further assistance..

---

**Now Removing `nvidia-304` and re-configuring `nvidia-319`**

Follow these steps to do so.. I am assuming that `nvidia-319` is currently installed in your system.

- Open terminal and execute following commands to completely `nvidia-304`

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove nvidia-304*
  sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-304*
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  ```
- Then execute these commands to re-configure `nvidia-319`

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-319
  ```

  if above command shows some error then try to replace `nvidia-319` with `nvidia-319*`

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  sudo update-initramfs -u (it would take some time)
  ```
- Then restart your system

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

Reply..

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow when I wake up. I'll come back with an answer on how it went as soon as I have tried this. I was actually going to try to update the kernel when you mentioned it earlier but I stopped just in case I would mess it up even more. So, tomorrow I'll come back with information about how it went.

Comment: Okey, I tried this and it did not help. I still get the same error. How do I update the NVIDIA kernel module to version 319.32?

Comment: That is what I wanted to check from you.. If you installed a new kernel 3.8.x and currently using that then you need to remove `nvidia-304` completely from your system.. and `reconfigure nvidia-319` to work properly.. I am editing my answer how can you do so.. Please give me 2 minutes..

Comment: check my answer.. Reply what happens..

Comment: I'll get back to this as soon as I can. I am in the middle of a big project right now so I'll leave my Ubuntu on the side for now, but I will fix it when I have time, and I really appreciate the help you're offering :) @SauravKumar

Comment: @SauravKumar i have a question, how come ubuntu lets you download the kernel w/c is 3.2.x and why is there a word rairing on the kernel 3.8.x, it seems like it is a kernel for ubuntu rairing ringtail? I'm also a beginner so i'm also confused.

Comment: @SauravKumar Had similar problem but I had driver versions 173, 319 and 331. I updated the kernel and removed 173 and 319 using your instructions and it workd.

Comment: @chanHXC "Since 13.04 is called raring and 12.04.3 is using packages equivalent to 13.04. This is the reason 12.04.3 packages are called *-lts-raring-packages and the same you see in your repository" from answer in [here]http://askubuntu.com/questions/341893/what-is-the-best-way-to-upgrade-the-kernel-in-12-04-3

Comment: @chanHXC: Say thanks to [kyng](http://askubuntu.com/users/76544/kyng) as he searched the best answer for you. If still you've any doubt and question you can start a new post. I'll try my best to give the solution for your question. and yes don't forget to comment the link of your question here, so that I'll reach to you easily.

Comment: for me doing the first steps upgrading the kernel was enough when I did the upgrade to nvidia-319 the problem reoccurred, after downgrading to nvidia-304 everything worked.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04 on ThinkPad W530 and I had a sever problem to start nvidia driver as I had the same problem but for version of 340 and it works for me. Thanks a lot.