# How to remove nvidia driver from ubuntu 16.04 kernel client and kernel module, or get kernel clent & module to use the same nvidia driver?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, xorg

After viewing /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log I found the following kernel issue:

```
NVRM: API mistmatch: the client has version 375.26, but
NVRM: this kernel module has the version 375.39. Please 
NVRM: make sure that kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
NVRM: components have the same version.
```

I found [Nvidia driver updated - mixed versions of 304.88 and 319.32](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342664/nvidia-driver-updated-mixed-versions-of-304-88-and-319-32) describing the same problem. To resolve my issue, I ran commands:

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
sudo apt-get autoremove nvidia375
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia*
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

The output from the last command confirmed no nvidia packages are installed. Thereafter, I ran:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

However, I am still experiencing the same kernel issue. Upon bootup, I am stuck in low graphics mode setup and kernel and /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log still complaining client has Nvidia driver 375.26 and kernel module has Nvidia driver 375.39.

My current kernel is 4.4.0-64-generic.

**Update1:** To see the nvidia modules read in by the kernel, I ran this command.

```
$ lsmod | grep nvidia
module            size    used by
nvidia_drm        53248   0
nvidia_modeset   790528   1 nvidia_drm
nvidia         12144640   1 nvidia_modeset
drm_helper       155648   2 i915_bpo,nvidia_drm
drm              364544   4 i915_bpo,drm_helper,nvidia_drm
```

Also found out using `modinfo module_name` that these modules are located in folder `/lib/modules/4.4.0-64-generic/updates/dkms/` and their filenames are `nvidia-drm.ko`, `nvidia-modeset.ko` and `nvidia.ko`, and their version is 375.39.

**2nd Question:** Why do these modules still exist even after I have purged all nvidia packages? Should I remove them? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by performing the following steps:

1. First reinstall the nvidia-418 repository graphic driver.
   **sudo apt-get install nvidia-418**

During the installation, I noticed that nvidia-418.26 driver was being installed.

2. I moved the entire /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/updates/dkms folder to my home directory backup folder. This was to make sure all old .ko files were removed.
   **sudo mv /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia* /home//backup**
3. I regenerated the .ko files for the installed driver using
   **sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-418**

   It created a new dkms folder with the relevant nvidia kernel modules. I also checked their version using command:

   **sudo modinfo /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko

   sudo modinfo /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_drm.ko

   sudo modinfo /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_modeset.ko

   sudo modinfo /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_uvm.ko**

   Their output showed that they were for version 418.26. **Great, this confirmed that the kernel client and kernel modules were referring to the same NVidia driver version.**
4. (Optional but recommended to ensure apt-get works correctly) Uninstall and reinstall the driver
   **sudo apt-get remove "*nvidia*"**
   **sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-418**
5. I rebooted the system with
   **sudo reboot**

Adapted from https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/525877/linux/api-mismatch-means-ubuntu-can-39-t-boot-i-can-39-t-fix-i-please-help-/1

Comment: This fixed my 17.10 upgrade with nvidia-384

Comment: Thanks, just remove that dkms folder fixed my same problem